# Set default options in VCR based on request URI

Tags: rspec, vcr

On all specs with requests to `example.com` I want to ignore the trailing id in the URI with respect the request matcher. Something like this.

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  # omitted
  c.register_request_matcher :uri_ignoring_trailing_id do |request_1, request_2|
    # omitted
  end

  c.before_http_request(lambda { |req| req.uri =~ /example.com/ }) do
    c.default_cassette_options = { match_requests_on: [ :uri_ignoring_trailing_id ] }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifying the global configuration in `before_http_request` is a bad idea because it'll affect *every* request made after you change the config, not just the ones matching `example.com`.  Here's how I would recommend you do this instead:

```
VCR.configure do |vcr|
  uri_matcher = VCR.request_matchers[:uri]
  vcr.register_request_matcher(:uri_ignoring_trailing_id_for_example_dot_com) do |req_1, req_2|
    if req_1.parsed_uri.host == "example.com" && req_2.parsed_uri.host == "example.com"
      # do your custom matching where you ignore trailing id
    else
      uri_matcher.matches?(req_1, req_2)
    end
  end

  vcr.default_cassette_options = { match_requests_on: [:method, :uri_ignoring_trailing_id_for_example_dot_com] }
end
```